# スロットマシンのフロー図

Tags: アルゴリズム

スロットマシンのフロー図を作りたいのですが、

スタートボタンを押すと３つのマスがそれぞれピロピロする。
それぞれのマスには、１～９の数字が１つづつ存在。
ストップボタンは３つあり、それぞれのマスをストップする。
３つの数字が揃えば、アタリと表示する。
３つの数字が揃わないとき、ハズレと表示する。
（ストップボタンをおさないと、10秒で自動停止する。）

この仕様だとどうやって作っていきますか？
また、繰り返し処理はいらないですよね？

Answer (score 1):

おそらく。繰り返し処理＝ある条件を満たしてなければ、もう一度繰り返す処理を指していると思いますので、

ストップボタンを押さないと１０秒で停止する、をより正確に条件を書くと、おそらくスロットマシンの動きですので、

1. "すべての"ストップボタンが押されているか
2. 開始してから１０秒間経過した

このどちらかを満たすまで、スロットマシンは動き続ける、つまり動くことを繰り返します。
では「具体的に何を繰り返す」のかを考えてみましょう。実は既に答えは書いています。

1または2の条件を満たしてスロットマシンの数字は停止します。
停止したときに3つの数字が全て同じであるかを判定しましょう。

文字だけで書くとわからないこともありますので、フロー図なので図示されると良いでしょう。

Answer (score 0):

環境が書いてないのですが、ロジックだけをフローに落とすのでしょうか？

＞繰り返し処理はいらないですよね？
なぜそう思ったのでしょう？
数字の表示にしても、１０秒間ボタン押下を待つにしても、
（イベント処理でもしない限り）繰り返しがないと何も出来ないと思いますが？

Comment: ただのフロー図ですので環境は気にしないでください。